# Leaflet see only one symbology at the time

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am working with Leaflet with nine layers and each have their own symbology like you can see in the image. For example, the first layer have 4 symbologys and you can see the colors in the map if you activate the layers, but you can see the colors in the legend all the time. I want that if you activate the layer, you can see the colors of the legend, but if i don't using this layer i only want to see the name of the layer.

Every layers is provided by a geoJson layer, i only find a solution for wms layer which is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/T8DHb/8/)   but there the symbology is an image and the layers are wms.

[image: Image - This is now]

Comment: What [layer control](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#layer-switching-controls) are you using? Can you share the relevant part of your layer control code editing your question?